# Is it possible to recuperate a file overwritten by Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, data-recovery, data-loss

I had an .odt file which was synced via Ubuntu One. I made changes on the file on my Ubuntu Computer. To check whether the file was synced I opened it on my Windows computer. It was not synced, but Ubuntu One *thought it was* and because I opened the file on Windows it took that file to be the newer one, thus overwriting the original file on Ubuntu... You get the point I guess. Bottom line: I lost my changes to the file.

Is there any way to revert back to the file before and get my original back? Is there any advanced setup tool for this available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can contact [Ubuntu One Support](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/). For the future you could use a version control system to keep track of your different files. There is a odtdiff possibility in git, for instance.